# BufferCell properties read-only?

Tags: powershell

I’m trying to set the [ForegroundColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.buffercell.foregroundcolor?view=pscore-6.2.0#System_Management_Automation_Host_BufferCell_ForegroundColor)  and [BackgroundColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.buffercell.backgroundcolor?view=pscore-6.2.0#System_Management_Automation_Host_BufferCell_BackgroundColor) properties of BufferCells allocated via [NewBufferCellArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostrawuserinterface.newbuffercellarray?view=pscore-6.2.0) in powershell.exe on Windows 10. I find that assignments appear to have no affect, e.g.

```
> $a = $Host.UI.RawUI.NewBufferCellArray("abc", [System.ConsoleColor]::White, [System.ConsoleColor]::Black)
> $a[0, 0].ForegroundColor
White
> $a[0, 0].ForegroundColor = [System.ConsoleColor]::Blue
> $a[0, 0].ForegroundColor
White
```

Per the documentation linked above, it seems both properties are supposed to have setters – are they not implemented in powershell.exe’s PSHostRawUserInterface classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some empirical testing, a workaround is to change the property on a temporary object and then assign that back to the array:

```bsh
> $x = $a[0,0]
> $x.ForegroundColor = [System.ConsoleColor]::Blue
> $x.ForegroundColor
Blue
> $a[0, 0] = $x
> $a[0, 0].ForegroundColor
Blue
```

I don't know the full details, but it's probably related to BufferCell being a struct rather than a class (see [source on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/1be3f4cc0e465ae11ad8e59e9060f5a59e4762eb/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/hostifaces/MshHostRawUserInterface.cs#L989)), so passing by Value rather than by Reference and / or NewBufferCellArray returning a *typed* array of BufferCell[,].

For comparison, see the behaviour of the following:

```bsh
$type = @"
public struct MyStruct
{
    System.ConsoleColor foregroundColor;
    public System.ConsoleColor ForegroundColor
    {
        get { return foregroundColor; }
        set { foregroundColor = value; }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $type;

$a = new-object -TypeName "MyStruct[]" 5;
$a[0].ForegroundColor = "Blue"
$a[0].ForegroundColor # Black

$a = new-object -TypeName "MyStruct[]" 5;
$x = $a[0];
$x.ForegroundColor = "Blue"
$a[0] = $x
$a[0].ForegroundColor # Blue

$a = @((new-object MyStruct))
$a[0].ForegroundColor = "Blue"
$a[0].ForegroundColor # Blue
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for investigating this! This seems indeed related to how arrays of structs are being projected into PS. Here's another workaround inspired by your research (abbrevations needed to meet SO msg length requirements):

Comment: ```
$type = @"
public static class Util
{
 public static void SetColor(
  System.Management.Automation.Host.BufferCell[,] arr,
  int i,
  int j,
  System.ConsoleColor fc,
  System.ConsoleColor bc)
 {
  arr[i, j].ForegroundColor = fc;
  arr[i, j].BackgroundColor = bc;
 }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $type

$a = $Host.UI.RawUI.NewBufferCellArray("abc", [ConsoleColor]::White, [ConsoleColor]::Black)

echo $a[0, 0].ForegroundColor

[Util]::SetColor($a, 0, 0, [System.ConsoleColor]::Red, [System.ConsoleColor]::Blue)

echo $a[0, 0].ForegroundColor

> White
> Red
```

Comment: Bummer, code fences don't seem to work in SO comments - I'm sure you get the gist despite the garbled formatting.